# href links are not clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have been working on a small project (just for fun and to practice my skills, with no intent to release).

I have put it on a free hosting services so others can see (the issue is also present on my local copy).

None of the links in the main content of the page are clickable, I assume due to some bad HTML and CSS.

Please can anyone suggest why

This is my [page](http://thats90s.net78.net/tv.php)

Comment: your code is not valid: you can't have a link as a direct child of an unordered list. Use a validator (http://validator.w3.org/) to test your pages

Comment: i saw some html code within your script tag all the way at the end. that won't work. you are getting some mysql errors there as well

Comment: Also I would change your z-index a bit, using 999 for a lot of stuff is ridiculous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have this:

```css
#content:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('images/bg2.png');
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 1500px;
}
```

And it is all over the page. So you can't reach the links

Answer (score 0):

In

```css
#content:after {
}
```

Just remove `content: '';`

So proper code CSS:

```css
#content:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('images/bg2.png');
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 1500px;
}
```

Everything else is OK.